# Front fill pandas DataFrame conditional on time

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following daily dataframe:

```
daily_index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2015', end='1/01/2018', freq='D')
random_values = np.random.randint(1, 3,size=(len(daily_index), 1))
daily_df = pd.DataFrame(random_values, index=daily_index, columns=['A']).replace(1, np.nan)
```

I want to map each value to a dataframe where each day is expanded to multiple 1 minute intervals. The final DF looks like so:

```
intraday_index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2015', end='1/01/2018', freq='1min')
intraday_df_full = daily_df.reindex(intraday_index)
# Choose random indices.
drop_indices = np.random.choice(intraday_df_full.index, 5000, replace=False)
intraday_df = intraday_df_full.drop(drop_indices)
```

In the final dataframe, each day is broken into 1 min intervals, but some are missing (so the minute count on each day is not the same). Some days have a value in the beginning of the day, but `nan` for the rest.

My question is, only for the days which start with some value in the first minute, how do I front fill for the rest of the day?

I initially tried to simply do the following `daily_df.reindex(intraday_index, method='ffill', limit=1440)`, but since some rows are missing, this cannot work. Maybe there a way to limit by time?

Comment: It's hard to show, because it's thousands of rows, since the data is of minute interval. The final output is the `intraday_df ` modified such that on the days where it start with some value (not nan), the same value is filled for the rest of the day. Does this help?

Comment: If you run the above code will give you the visual of the data. It's fully stand alone functional.

Comment: sorry my fault I'm not 100% sure but you could try something like `intraday_df.groupby(intraday_df.index.date)['A'].transform('ffill')` should work

Comment: Indeed it worked (with slight modification) `intraday_df.groupby(intraday_df.index.date).transform('ffill')` You should post as answer. Can you also explain why he groupy does not change the structure of the index of the `intraday_df` and what does `transform` do in this scenario?

Comment: since you modified the above, why don't you post an answer and I'll edit what transform does for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Datanovice's comments, this line achieves the desired result:

```
intraday_df.groupby(intraday_df.index.date).transform('ffill')
```

where my [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) defines the desired groups on which we want to apply the operation and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) does this without modifying the DataFrame's index.

Comment: nice one, don't forget to green tick when you can so this Q can be closed. :)